# If $A$ and $B$ are bounded sets show that $A⊂B$ implies $\mathrm{diam}(A)≤ \mathrm{diam}(B)$

Tags: functional-analysis

Below is what I attempt,

Let $\mathrm{diam}(A) < m$ and $\mathrm{diam}(B) < n$

Let $A⊂B$

Say, $\mathrm{diam}(A)> \mathrm{diam}(B)$

$\implies m>n$

which contradicts our supposition that $A⊂B$

thus, $\mathrm{diam}(A)≤ \mathrm{diam}(B)$.

Is my solution correct?

Comment: What are $m,n$?

Comment: I corrected my question. Read it again. Thanks

Comment: First, if we had $diam(A)=2,m=3,diam(B)=1,n=4$ then $diam(A)<m,diam(B)<n,diam(A)>diam(B)$ but $m<n$, so your conclusion that $m>n$ is wrong. Second, why would $m>n$ contradict $A\subseteq B$?

Comment: Can you please tell me the exact solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\diam}{\text{diam}}$
$$\diam(A)=\sup\{\|x-y\|\mid x,y\in A\}\quad\text{and}\quad \diam(B)=\sup\{\|x-y\|\mid x,y\in B\}.$$
Since $A\subset B$,$$\{\|x-y\|\mid x,y\in A\subset B\}\subset \{\|x-y\|\mid x,y\in B\}.$$
The result follows. The thing you can add is the proof of $$A\subset B\implies \sup A\leq \sup B.$$

Comment: This assumes $x$ and $y$ are in a space in which subtraction is possible. (Although of course one could just slightly alter the notation, or one could abstain from taking it literally.) ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: If the subtraction is not possible, It's easy to adapt the proof in any metric metric space...

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\diam}{\operatorname{diam}}$$A\subset B$ means every member of $A$ is a member of $B$.  That is a definition.

$\diam(A)$ is usually defined as $\sup\{d(x,y) : x,y\in A\}$.  That is a definition.

Recall also the definition of "upper bound" and "smallest upper bound".

If $A\subset B$ then every distance between two points in $A$ is a distance between two points in $B$, since if the two points are in $A$, then they are in $B$, by the first definition above.  Therefore

$$
\{d(x,y):x,y\in A\} \subset \{d(x,y): x,y\in B\}.
$$
The number $\diam(B)$ is the smallest upper bound of the latter of those two sets.  That implies $\diam(B)$ is an upper bound of $B$.  That means $\diam(B) \ge\text{every distance between two points of }B$.  But every distance between two points of $A$ is a distance between two points of $B$, since all points in $B$ are in $A$.  Hence $\diam(B)$ is $\ge\text{all distances between points of } A$.  Thus $\diam(B)$ is an upper bound of the set of all distances between points of $A$.  Hence $\diam(B)\ge \text{the smallest upper bound of all distances between points of } A$.  The latter smallest upper bound is $\diam(A)$.  So $\diam(B)\ge\diam(A)$.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but your attempt is not good at proving what you're required to. You're basically proving that, if $m>n$ then it is false that $m\le n$.

---

Let's see what $\def\diam{\operatorname{diam}}\diam(A)$ is. Consider the set $A^*$ of all numbers you obtain by doing $d(x,y)$ where $x,y\in A$ ($d$ is the distance function on the space you're working in).

Then $\diam(A)=\sup A^*$, by definition.

Now, if $A\subset B$, that is, every point in $A$ is also in $B$, we get immediately that $A^*\subset B^*$, so our real task is showing that, if $P$ and $Q$ are sets of real numbers such that $P\subset Q$, then $\sup P\le\sup Q$.

This will follow from the observation that any upper bound for $Q$ is also an upper bound for $P$. Therefore the *least* upper bound for $Q$ is an upper bound for $P$, hence it is greater than or equal to the *least* upper bound for $P$. In other words, $\sup P\le \sup Q$.